# Get the last line of any word document using macros VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, file-rename

I have lots of word documents to rename using the lastline of the document.
The lastline of the document starts with: "Expediente N°", so this is how I've tried to solve the problem unsuccessfully.

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Expediente N° "
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
MsgBox Selection.Text
```

Remember that the last line could be dinamically, for example "Expediente N° 334234" or "Expediente N° 1111", that why I think the solution in get the entire last line of the document.

Comment: If there's a fixed format to those number then have you considered using wildcard? If entire last line means the last paragraph of the document then `doc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text` should get you that line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some times, after writing a paragraph, you may press Enter (even more times). The next code will return the last paragraph text, above such a end line character:

```
Sub testLastParagraphText()
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last
    Do While p.Range.Text = Chr(13)
        Set p = p.Previous
    Loop
    Debug.Print p.Range.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: I think your `If..Else..End If` can be eliminated.  Looks like you only need `Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last: Do While p.Range.Text = Chr(13): Set p = p.Previous: Loop: Debug.Print p.Range.Text`

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld That's correct, of course... I firstly tried the `Paragraphs.Last` and it returned the end of line. Then added above a loop to skip what not necessary. Instead of deleting my first attempt, I inserted an `Else`... :) I will adapt the code to make it as it should be. Thanks!